# Find relations between polynomials

Tags: polynomials

I have a question regarding the relationship between two polynomials. (I'm still a beginner and don't know so many commands.) Is there any option to show me the relation between two polynomials? As an example, if

$f=x^2+2x+3$,

$g=3x^3+6x+9$

then to have an output like $3f=g$.

Comment: You can divide them with `Simplify[(3x^3+6x+9)/(x^3+2x+3)]` (assuming you mean $x^3$ instead of $x^2$ for $f$)

Comment: `polys = {f == x^3 + 2 x + 3, g == 3 x^3 + 6 x + 9}; Eliminate[polys, x]`

Comment: @BobHanlon This just give me the Output: False

Comment: `Clear` any previous definitions, i.e., `Clear[f, g, x]`

Comment: `f == x^3 + 2 x + 3; g == 3 x^3 + 6 x + 9;` and `{q, r} = PolynomialQuotientRemainder[g, f, x]`. Also explore, `PolynomialReduce`, `GroebnerBasis`, `PolynomialGCD`.

Comment: People here generally like users to post code as *Mathematica* code instead of just images or TeX, so they can copy-paste it. It makes it convenient for them and more likely you will get someone to help you. You may find [the meta Q&A, How to copy code from Mathematica so it looks good on this site,](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1584) helpful

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- When `f=x^3 + 2 x + 3`

`GroebnerBasis` work for another complex cases.

```
Clear[f, g, basis];
{f, g} = {x^3 + 2 x + 3, 3 x^3 + 6 x + 9};
basis = GroebnerBasis[{f, g}, x]
```

> `{3 + 2 x + x^3}`

It means that `f` and `g` have comment divisor.

```
PolynomialReduce[f, basis, {x}][[1]]
PolynomialReduce[g, basis, {x}][[1]]
```

> `{1}`
> `{3}`

That is `g=3f`.

- When `f=x^2 + 2 x + 3`

```
Clear[f, g, basis];
{f, g} = {x^2 + 2 x + 3, 3 x^3 + 6 x + 9};
basis = GroebnerBasis[{f, g}, x]
```

> `{1}`

It measns that `f` and `g` are coprime

```
{d, {a, b}} = PolynomialExtendedGCD[f, g, x]
{f, g} . {a, b} == d
% // Simplify
```

> `True`.

> `f*1/54 (15 - 9 x + 3 x^2) + g*1/162 (3 - 3 x) == 1`